# Sequelize self association insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint fkey

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError when creating self association

```js
const Category=sequelize.define('Category',{
        name:{ type:DataTypes.STRING, defaultValue: '' },
        parentCategoryId:{ type:DataTypes.INTEGER},
        });

    Category.associate = (models) => {
        Category.hasMany(models.Category, {as: 'subCategories', foreignKey: 'parentCategoryId'});
        Category.belongsTo(models.Category, {as: 'parent', foreignKey: 'parentCategoryId'});
    };
```

```
Trace: { SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError: insert or update on table  violates foreign key constraint fkey
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete association column and sync again

```
ALTER TABLE public."Categories" DROP "parentCategoryId"
```

Then sync again with sequilize, it will create the correct association

be careful this will delete old `parentCategoryId` column data